# VB.Net Web Browser controls not working

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to implement a simple web browser in Visual Studio 2013 using VB.Net. However, when I run the application, only the **GO** button works, and none of the other functions are firing, except for the `Form1_Load` function. Please help me.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim int As Integer = 0
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com")
    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button9_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        WebBrowser1.ShowPropertiesDialog()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        WebBrowser1.GoBack()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        WebBrowser1.GoForward()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        WebBrowser1.Refresh()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        WebBrowser1.Stop()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com")
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Your subs are not handling any event.

Comment: If you find my answer solve the problem, please select it as the accepted answer

Comment: yes. had to wait 10 minutes though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `Handles Button1.Click`, `Handles Button2.Click`, etc to each sub